# How to send photos from a computer to another (non locally) using JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, client

I want to make a java program that sends photos taken with the web camera from a computer to another, that aren't connected in LAN.

I was able to make the program take photos and convert them to a file but I can't succeed in sending them to the other computer.

I don't necessarily want to send photos but any form of data. I'm new to this kind of approach so I might be making a lot of mistakes as I'm not really sure how it is supposed to work.

The code I tried so far:

Client (the computer I want to send data from, it should take a screenshot and send it to the server):

```
public class GreetingClient
{
    Image newimg;
    static BufferedImage bimg;
    byte[] bytes;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String serverName = "127.0.0.1";//tried "localhost" and my actual ip adress as well.
        int port = 6066;
        try
        {
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
            Robot bot;
            bot = new Robot();
            bimg = bot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            ImageIO.write(bimg,"JPG",client.getOutputStream());
            client.close();
        } catch(IOException | AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server code (the computer that should receive the data):

```
public class Main extends Thread
{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket server;

    public Main(int port) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(180000);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                server = serverSocket.accept();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(server.getInputStream()));
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.pack();

            }
            catch(SocketTimeoutException st)
            {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                break;
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception
    {
        Thread t = new Main(6066);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

It works when I try to send data from my pc to my pc (if that makes sense) but when I try sending data from another computer that is not locally connected to mine it doesn't work.

I want to make this without having to activate port forwarding if that's possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".

Comment: Do port forwarding. Seriously. You have to use port forwarding to connect one home computer to another... if you prefer to spend money instead, you can rent a "virtual private server" that won't have port forwarding, but that costs money.

Comment: @user253751 thank you for the VPS idea, I was thinking about getting a VPS but I'm not really sure how to code it with java, I guess I'll just do some research haha

Comment: @user207421 by "doesn't work" I mean that it doesn't connect at all to the server, the exception given is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: @eddie it's a computer, probably running linux with ssh access, so if you are able to install java on a linux computer using ssh - which is pretty much the same as doing it with only the command prompt - that's how

Comment: @eddie yes you need port forwarding

Answer (score -1):

You can also write a simple client-server chat app in java, and then send messages of converted JPG to e.g. Base64. Then, when received decode them. So the beginning would be writing chat app and then writing new functionality to automatically convert JPG to Base64 and display images in the window:

//Server:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
public class MyServer {  
public static void main(String[] args){  
try{  
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(3456);  
Socket s=ss.accept();//establishes connection   
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
String  str=(String)dis.readUTF();  
System.out.println("message= "+str);  
ss.close();  
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
}  
}
```

//Client:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
public class MyClient {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
try{      
Socket s=new Socket("localhost",3456);  
DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");  
dout.flush();  
dout.close();  
s.close();  
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
}  
}
```

//Image display:

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
  
public class MyCanvas extends Canvas{  
      
    public void paint(Graphics g) {  
  
        Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
        Image i=t.getImage("p3.gif");  
        g.drawImage(i, 120,100,this);  
          
    }  
        public static void main(String[] args) {  
        MyCanvas m=new MyCanvas();  
        JFrame f=new JFrame();  
        f.add(m);  
        f.setSize(400,400);  
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }  
  
}
```

//Conversion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
 
           File f =  new File("/opt/myImage.jpg");
             String encodstring = encodeFileToBase64Binary(f);
             System.out.println(encodstring);
       }
 
       private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File file) throws Exception{
            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes), "UTF-8");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, the thing is that file conversion and things like that are not that much of a problem for me, I can't figure out how to send the file non-locally. It works with "localhost" but only on my machine, when I try it from another machine that's not LAN connected it doesn't work.

Comment: Are You sure that firewall stuff and so on are allowing connection? I had the same problem with chat app in java and turning firewall off completely helped

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't help

Comment: Some basic Java I/O coding errors here. No need for base-64 encoding.